# Logs not loading in web UI after update

Tags: python, airflow

We recently updated to Airflow 1.10.7 from 1.10.3 (Python 2.7). Things seem to be working except for two problems related to the web UI that were not issues in 1.10.3:

(1) If we zoom in on a subdag and then click "Code," the display has the name of parent.subdag as expected but the code shown is for the parent. It's not showing any sort of error and the subdags are running properly, so it's not clear where to starting looking into this problem.

(2) More critical, attempting to load any logs results in a constant loading symbol. Inspecting the page displays the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/decorators.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 26, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/decorators.py", line 56, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/views.py", line 637, in get_logs_with_metadata
    logs, metadata = _get_logs_with_metadata(try_number, metadata)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/views.py", line 628, in _get_logs_with_metadata
    logs, metadatas = handler.read(ti, try_number, metadata=metadata)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 169, in read
    log, metadata = self._read(task_instance, try_number_element, metadata)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 98, in _read
    log_relative_path = self._render_filename(ti, try_number)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 75, in _render_filename
    jinja_context = ti.get_template_context()
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/apache_airflow_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1149, in get_template_context
    if 'tables' in task.params:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

The logs are being written to the expected output location on our machine (we are not using remote logging), so it's not that the logs themselves are missing. Not sure if this is an Airflow bug or a configuration issue.

From our config files:

```
# Log format
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s

# Flag to enable/disable Colored logs in Console
# Colour the logs when the controlling terminal is a TTY.
colored_console_log = False

# Log format for when Colored logs is enabled
# colored_log_format = [%%(blue)s%%(asctime)s%%(reset)s] {{%%(blue)s%%(filename)s:%%(reset)s%%(lineno)d}} %%(log_color)s%%(levelname)s%%(reset)s - %%(log_color)s%%(message)s%%(reset)s
# colored_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.colored_log.CustomTTYColoredFormatter

# Log filename format
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
...
# Name of handler to read task instance logs.
# Default to use file task handler.
# task_log_reader = file.task
task_log_reader = task
```